# $T$ is invertible.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

> Let $(e_j)$  an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $T$ an unbounded operator self adjoint on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\forall n\in \Bbb  N  ;||T(e_n)||>c||e_n||$ where $c>0$.

Can we say $T$ is invertible?.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: If $T=Id$ the result is correct,  but if $T\not=Id$, i don't have any information

Comment: Did you mean a bounded operator or unbounded?

Comment: unbounded operator

Comment: Presuming that $(e_j)$ is a Hilbert basis, then every element $L^2$ can be expressed in terms of them only as the limit of an infinite sum. but $T$ is unbounded = discontinuous. I.e. there are cases where $\lim T(v_n) \ne T(\lim v_n)$. Can you see how that might be exploited?

Comment: @Paul Sinclair, see this pdf, page 11:   http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781441994752-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1143146-p174103301

Comment: It is possible that an unbounded operator is continuous

Comment: Since the pdf you linked to starts with page 21, I have no idea what you think page 11 is going to provide. However, *you* obviously need to read theorem 2.1 (page 22), which directly contradicts your previous comment. But even if you were right, it would make no difference. All you need is one non-invertible $T$. You might want to think about the subspace of $L^2$ formed by *finite* linear combinations of the $e_j$, and about it's orthogonal complement.

Comment: Ahh. I see. You were referring to the pdf's page counter, not the document page numbers  A poor terminology, since the "un" prefix in English means "not" and this definition is not equivalent to "not bounded".. But even so, the existence of continuous "unbounded" operators is immaterial. They don't deny the existence of discontinuous unbounded operators.